# Why this js condition does not work - if ( xxx === undefined )

Tags: javascript, undefined

I though this signature should work, but it throws me an error and stop continuing the script.

```
if ( xxx === undefined ) alert('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
```

Why it does not work. It should work. I found a lot of answers which mentioned this signature to test if variable is undefined.

Comment: What error do you get? "xxx is undefined" ?

Comment: that's what you'll get with strict mode javascript unless you declare xxx

Comment: This will only throw an error if xxx has not been declared before

Comment: Could you test, `if (typeof xxx === typeof undefined) alert('aaaaa')` ?? Actually, on my local, the code you provide it doesn't work, because `xxx` is not declared. If I use the `let xxx; if( xxx === undefined).....` then the statement returns true.

Comment: @Merianos How would `if (typeof undefined === typeof undefined)` ever be any different than `if (true)`?

Comment: @deceze what you mean? I don't understand your question :)

Comment: @Merianos I'm saying that suggesting to test `if (typeof undefined === typeof undefined)` seems pretty pointless…!?

Comment: @deceze you are right. I wrote my comment in the wrong. I am going to fix it ;) Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check a variable for existing you need to make use of typeof

```js
if ( typeof xxx === 'undefined' ) alert('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
```

If you dont do so you will get an error:

> xxx is not defined

Comment: Yes I konw about typeof but I expected that my condition will work.